# Using colorbox to process user registration and response in same colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, colorbox

My adventures continue...
On my page, I want to display a registration form in colorbox, allow the user to submit the form which is processed by a php script and then display a thank you style message in the colorbox which the user will then close.

At the moment I have the processing script in the same page as the form and this works on it's own outside of colorbox.

I've seen similar questions here that suggests to post the form using an ajax call

```
$('form').live('submit', function(e){
var successHref = this.action,
    errorHref = "formError.php";

e.preventDefault();
$('#cboxLoadingGraphic').fadeIn();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processForm.php",
    data: {someData: $("#someData").val()},
    success: function(response) {
        if(response=="ok") {
            console.log("response: "+response);
            $.colorbox({
                open:true,
                href: successHref   
            });
        } else {
            $.colorbox({
                open:true,
                href: errorHref
            });
        }
    },
    dataType: "html"
});

return false;
});
```

I'm a bit confused with this....

I think I'm ok with sending my form via $,ajax (although any clarity appreciated) but I'm not clear how to handle the response from the form. What do I need my php script to output (and how) so that a thank you message is displayed? Is it simply an echo statement from the php script?

Should I also separate out my processing script from the form )i did it this way as I kept getting path errors and it was easier at the time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success!

I've managed to get it to work - all logical in the end - shame I'm not very logical..

First move was to separate the php form process script out into a separate file.

Colorbox link to the form all works ok

Used an ajax post to the php script and waited for a message back from the php script.

The php script produces two html messages depending on success or failure which are then displayed in the colorbox by replacing the form html in its div

Yay!